# How to return a list of a defined type WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have defined the data contract as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class TestResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public string[] NegResponses { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Pass { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Request { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to return a list of the above type in the operation contract as follows:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(TestFault))]
    List<TestResult> Tester(string nodeCaption);
```

And what else I have to look into to return a list of a type that has been defined ?

By the way I guess I am not using svcutil  and instead using channel factory as follows:

```
        private static readonly ITestService TestClient;

        // initialize a channel factory
        var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ITestService>(new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), endPoint);

        // Create a channel
        TestClient = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Have you tried consuming this service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client-side and the server-side should share the same service contract and data contract. This is fundamental that we could consume the service on the client-side.
Here is an example, wish it is useful to you.
**Server-side.**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:21011");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), uri))
            {
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
                smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb == null)
                {
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                    {
                        HttpGetEnabled=true
                    };
                    sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                }
                Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");

                sh.Opened += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is ready");
                };
                sh.Closed += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is clsoed");
                };
                sh.Open();
                Console.ReadLine();
                //pause
                sh.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<Product> SayHello();
    }
    public class MyService : IService
    {
        public List<Product> SayHello()
        {
            return new List<Product>()
            {
                new Product()
                {
                    ID=1,
                    Name="Apple"
                },
                new Product()
                {
                    ID=2,
                    Name="Pear"
                }
            };
        }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "MyNamespace")]
    public class Product
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Client-side (Console application,we call the service with ChannelFactory).**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://10.157.13.69:21011");
            ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
            IService service = factory.CreateChannel();
            try
            {
                var result = service.SayHello();
                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"ID:{item.ID}\n,Name:{item.Name}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<Product> SayHello();
    }
    [DataContract(Namespace = "MyNamespace")]
    public class Product
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Data Contract should be decorated with Namespace property, this will guarantee that the serialization and deserialization process properly). Actually, the service contract also needs a namespace to represent the practical method name, which will be used to addressing the method on the server-side. but there is a default value in the namespace.

> http://tempuri.org

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.